# Collapsable Item

Tags: javascript, jquery

So, I want a collapsable item. When you go to the page, there would be something in the bottom right corner, and when you click on it, it slides up (with a transition), if you click on this again, it would slide down. How could this be executed with JS? Thanks!

Comment: You should look into [jquery accordion](http://jqueryui.com)

Comment: You're describing accordion tabs, there are tons of different solutions for this, including one in jQuery-ui: https://jqueryui.com/accordion/, just google "accordion tabs," pick your favorite and try it out

Comment: do not ask such kind of question again in this platform.

Answer (score 0):

you can get easily answered such kind of questions from http://www.w3schools.com/

Try following code provided by JQuery

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div data-role="page" id="pageone">
    <div data-role="header">
      <h1>Collapsible Sets</h1>
    </div>

    <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
      <div data-role="collapsibleset">
          <div data-role="collapsible">
              <h3>Click me - I'm collapsible!</h3>
              <p>I'm the expanded content.</p>
          </div>
      <div data-role="collapsible">
          <h3>Click me - I'm collapsible!</h3>
          <p>I'm the expanded content.</p>
      </div>
      <div data-role="collapsible">
         <h3>Click me - I'm collapsible!</h3>
         <p>I'm the expanded content.</p>
      </div>
    <div data-role="collapsible">
       <h3>Click me - I'm collapsible!</h3>
       <p>I'm the expanded content.</p>
      </div>
     </div>
   </div>

   <div data-role="footer">
     <h1>Insert Footer Text Here</h1>
   </div>
</div> 

</body>
</html>
```

otherwise you can use div with show hide functionality on click. That also will be very simple.